# Generic WinForms ListView (with regards to Tag)

Tags: winforms, listview, tags, generics, typed

I'm trying to improve on a Winforms project where datatable rows are stored in the Tag property of ListViewItems. When the datatable is refactored to List<T> (or actually classes containing lists) it would help immensely if I could make the Tag property generic by using a subclass of ListView.

In the best of worlds, I'd want the Tag property to be replaced by a public T Tag{get; set;} that wraps base.Tag and casts it.
Second best would be Obsoleting Tag and providing a new property like TypedTag working like above.

I think this would involve subclassing or composite aggregation of at least ListView, ListViewItemCollection, SelectedListViewItemCollection and ListViewItem, and I'm not sure how to do it.

In short:

```
ListView<Employee> lvwEmployees;
```

should result in this being possible:

```
Employee selected = lvwEmployees.SelectedItems[0].TypedTag;
```

And give a compilation error for this:

```
DataRow selected = lvwEmployees.SelectedItems[0].TypedTag;
```

Is it possible? Is it already done?
Project is dotnet 2.0 but I think I'll try to have it upgraded if it helps this matter.

EDIT: It turns out that the owner constructor argument is all a certain collection needs to hook up to the inner collection. Hence the following works:

```
ListView a = new ListView();
a.Items.Add("Hello");
Assert.AreEqual(1, new ListView.ListViewItemCollection(a).Count);
```

This makes it rather easy to create a generic tagged ListView. I'll post a complete solution later. :)

EDIT2: Here's the solution:
http://thecarlr.blogspot.com/2010/11/generic-listview.html

EDIT3: For designer support, just add a non generic subclass and use that.
Example: If you intended to use ListView<Employee> in the form, create a ListViewEmployee : ListView<Employee> in another file, and use ListViewEmployee in the form.

The easiest way to add one of theese listviews would be to add a normal listview to the form, and then change it's type in the source files. (And if you don't know where it's declared or instantiated, find out or use the normal listview instead.)

Comment: There's discussion of a similar topic at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1126404/is-there-an-easy-way-to-associate-an-event-with-a-listviewitem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solution:
http://thecarlr.blogspot.com/2010/11/generic-listview.html

Enjoy :)

/Carl

Comment: The major problem with this solution is that the generic ListView<> cannot be used within the Designer. So unless you intend to hand write all the UI code (or post edit the Designer.cs), this solution isn't very useful.

Comment: Ah, thanks for noticing and letting me know! I've got to look into that. :)

Comment: It seems like the designer problem is really not a problem. All I needed to do was to inherit again into a non generic class and use that instead.

Answer (score 1):

You made the wrong class generic.  SelectedItems[0] is a ListViewItem, not a ListView.

There isn't anything you can do to change the type of the Items and SelectedItems properties.  You can certainly derive your own class from ListViewItem and just add the property you want to store.  No need for another Tag property.  You'll have no trouble adding them but you'll need to cast back to your derived class when you retrieve them back from the Selected/Items collection.

In general, avoid this kind of code by using the ListView only as a view of your model.  The ListViewItem.Index should then always be good to get a typesafe reference back from your model.

Comment: I want to make a whole chain of classes, not just ListViewItem.
It's no problem making the structure, but construction and assignment of ListViewItem's Item which is private (or not implemented) is more problematic.

Comment: Erm, you can make any number of distinct listview item classes.  As long as they derive from ListViewItem.  Otherwise you can't add them to the ListView's Item collection.  There are private members inside ListViewItem that are needed to keep Windows happy.

Comment: Yes, but the ListView's Item collection isn't generic, hence it needs to be overridden.

Comment: Yes, but as noted in my answer, you cannot override the Items property.  It isn't virtual.

Comment: Yes, I know. That's why the word aggregation is mentioned in the OP. However, I think I pretty much fixed it now. :)

Answer (score 0):

VS Designer simply cannot handle abstract or generic controls ([not for want of asking](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/253384/abstract-and-generic-controls-and-forms-support-in-the-winforms-designer)).

One way around that limitation is to write a type safe wrapper around a standard `ListView`.

Something like this:

```
public class TypedListView<T> where T : class
{
    public TypedObjectListView(ListView lv) {
        this.lv = lv;
    }
    private ListView lv;

    public virtual T SelectedObject {
        get { return (T)this.lv.SelectedItems[0].Tag; }
    }

    // Lots more methods/properties
}
```

You create a normal ListView in Designer, and then when you wanted to access it, you create and use your adapter instead. Like this:

```
var typedListView = new TypedListView<Employee>(this.listView1);
Employee selectedEmployee = typedListView.SelectedObject;
```

You would need to provide a typed version of every `ListView` properties or method you wanted to use.

The [ObjectListView](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/list/ObjectListView.aspx) project takes this approach to create a `TypedObjectListView` which does exactly what are you asking for.

Comment: Wow, ObjectListView looks really nice. I've got to look into that one. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I like the adapter idea btw, but it's not ideal in that it's easy to go through the normal variable such that there are rows with other types of "Tag".